# Developing expressions using and or not

Tags: python, operators

Alice, Bob, Charlie, David, and Eve are friends trying to decide whether to go skiing or study next weekend. Each casts a vote. Let their votes be de- noted by predicates a, b, c, d, and e where each is True if the preference is for skiing, and False if the preference is for studying. Write a python formula (using and, or, not, and parentheses – no ”if” statements or other Python operators allowed) that is True if the majority wants to ski, and False if the majority wants to study. Note that you can break long lines in Python with a backslash.
Hint: Do not make a function. The answer should be a single expression using variables a, b, c, d and e, plus operators and, or and not.

Example:
(a or b or c) and (a or b or d)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is a homework question and suggest you enumerate (in English, using the words and, or, not) all possible situations in which a majority want to ski, then translate that sentence into python code.

To start you out, consider the situation where Alice, Bob and Charlie want to ski - this is a majority - represented by the predicate (a and b and c)